# Issue : Setting up in Devenv Vagrant Fabric v1.4 with PBFT consensus problem

Tags: docker, vagrant, hyperledger-fabric

*Notice: I am an early starter on Hyperledger Fabric*

I am trying to set up hyperledger fabric in devenv **vagrant** to activate the consensus PBFT plugin protocol to set up a starter network. However, I am having some issues with core.yaml file and docker-composer.yml file (extracted these files to *vagrant $HOME*).

**docker-composer.yml** file .

```
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: peer node start
```

**core.yaml** file has the standard setup that can be found in `sampleconfig` folder. Tried to look for `peer.validator.consensus` to be set to `= pbft` in the file. However, with no success. Entry could not be found in the file.

It would be very helpful to have a "pre-configured" fabric network repository that would be easy further configured and change to PBFT with corresponding orgs and peers.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for PBFT.
The current architecture of Hyperledger Fabric 1.x is very different from the 0.5/0.6 architecture.  Fabric 1.x has two types of nodes:  peers and orderers.  Orderers are used to order and batch transactions into blocks and deliver the blocks to peers.  Currently, the consensus mechanisms for the ordering service are Solo (single node) and Kafka-based.  Work on Raft is underway.